# setCardBackgroundColor() set wrong color

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am programmatically trying to set the color of a CardView using the function setCardBackgroundColor() but the color is showing up incorrectly.

- If I set the color to black(#000000) it shows up as medium gray.
- If I set the color to white(#ffffff) or green(#9ccb3f) it shows up as violet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are not sending in the id of the color (i.e. R.color.COLOR_NAME)

Comment: Ahh this solved it, would be nice if Android studio had lint to detect this

Comment: @toidiu it does `@ColorInt` and `@ColorRes` anotations. Unfortunately this method is not annotated though :(